# Disable HTML respond format in whole Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I use pure javascript frontend template to handle all requests with Rails via JSON API

However,

I don't know why sometimes the exception will give me the error message in HTML format.

Because I've already set the API request format in JSON

## Controller (I only keep format.json in the controller)

```
format.json { render json: @city.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

## Route.rb

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    resources country do
        resources city do
            .....
        end
    end
    end
  end
```

Comment: why don't you use Grape and Swagger to build your APIs my friend. Refs: https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape, https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-swagger-rails. Hope this help. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why sometimes the exception will give me the error
>   message in HTML format.

It's not dependent on your app, it is all about the request and request headers, if somebody make a request as html rails try to render html.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are rendered in html outside of your controller. You should do it by yourself:

your controller:

```
begin
  code_for_ok
rescue #some exception
  render json: @city.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

Comment: I assume the exception here is `ActionController::UnknownFormat`.